# Google Consent Screen Options\scopes checked by default

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

Is it possible for the consent screen sensitive scopes to be checked by default? Is something I need to change in code or in the google's project console?

[image]